# Trouble setting up a reverse proxy on apache for ramaze (rack) app

Tags: apache, rack, httpd.conf

[Using these instructions](http://www.concept47.com/austin_web_developer_blog/devops/how-to-try-out-puma-with-apache-proxy-right-now/) I am trying to setup a reverse proxy for my ramaze/rack app.

Below is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/"> 
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        # AllowOverride All

        # desbest edit
        AllowOverride None

        Require local
    </Directory>

    # desbest edit
    ProxyPass "/compesh/"  "http://127.0.0.1:7000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/compesh/"  "http://127.0.0.1:7000/"

</VirtualHost>
#
```

I get an Error 404 File Not Found, when I load up my app and my app never shows.

[image: error 404 not found on rack]

How do I make my app show when I load up http://localhost/compesh

I'm having trouble making my app show.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: I have successfully followed those instructions and my rack/ramaze app still has the same error when I load up the directory in the web browser.